# PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "musicians" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku

`rake db:migrate` works locally in `sqlite3` but does not work in `postgresql` in heroku.

**ERROR**

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "musicians" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "orders" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_ad134589be"
FOREIGN KEY ("musician_id")
  REFERENCES "musicians" ("id")
   (0.9ms)  ROLLBACK
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "musicians" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "orders" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_ad134589be"
FOREIGN KEY ("musician_id")
```

Here is a link to the entire log: https://gist.github.com/helloravi/2cb69e0927e63e186b09

The following is the migration which does not get executed. The error is displayed below the migration code

```
class CreateAlbums < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :albums do |t|
      t.string :album_name
      t.references :musician, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :albums, :users, column: :musician_id
  end
end
```

I have a users table with a musician column which is boolean(some users are musicians)

I even tried using `add_foreign_key` and still I am not able to figure out what the problem is.

I tried `rake db:schema:load` and it worked. I want to be able to make `rake db:migrate` work because I need to be able to migrate in production.

Comment: Have you run `heroku run rake db:migrate`?

Comment: That is what is not working Pavan

Comment: Could you also paste in associations part in `app/models/album.rb`?

Comment: ` belongs_to :musician, class_name: User.name`
`  has_many :songs`
`  has_many :order_items`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite does not check foreign keys, it simply ignores them. But PostgreSQL is very strict and raises an error when the foreign key constraint is not valid.

Rails [foreign_key](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_foreign_key) does not support what you want it to do. When you write `t.references :musician` then there must be a `musicians` table. But you want the foreign key to point to a `users` table.

I see two options:

1. Use `t.references :users` and rename that association in your `albums.rb` like this:

   ```
   belongs_to :musician, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user_id'
   ```
2. Or: you just use `t.integer :musician_id` instead of `references` and define the foreign key constraint manually with an `execute 'ALTER TABLE ...'`

Comment: 1. I will probably go with option one. I am already using the association the way you suggested.
2. How would I manually execute the `execute 'ALTER TABLE ...'` in heroku ?
3. Would it work if I deleted the line with t.references and used `add_foreign_key` line in the migration?

Answer (score 1):

What @spickermann said is correct.
Changing your migration to the following should work:

```
class CreateAlbums < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :albums do |t|
      t.string :album_name
      t.integer :musician_id
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :albums, :users, column: :musician_id
    add_index :albums, :musician_id
  end
end
```

Comment: What would be the command which would create a migration of what you mentioned?(I was also planning to do what Speckerman said)

Comment: You could just edit the migration. The existing migration will not work on postgresql. You will have to make a change to the existing migration. Making this change will not effect what happens with sqlite3.

Comment: I am asking for a command for future not now. Right now I am just taking this advice :)